# Creating CoverageStore using REST API from GeoTIFF already in GeoServer DATA_DIR

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I have a GeoTIFF already available in GeoServer DATA_DIR, specifically in a subdir named "rice" and I woluld like to publish it as a CoverageStore.

What I could understand is that REST API allows to create the coverage with a PUT request passing the file as the payload.
How can I skip this step?
The only [documented option](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/coveragestores.html#workspaces-ws-coveragestores-cs-file-extension) seem to allow for just the 'file[.extension]' option that requires passing in a file.
On the other side, datastores allow for an 'external' option that allows picking from DATA_DIR.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is using the PUT method and send a request with both a payload and a couple of querystring parameters.

Most notably,  is that **there is no need to move GeoTIFF coverage to GeoServer Data DIR** provided that the GeoServer instance (so its container - e.g. Tomcat) can reach the GeoTIFF file in Server's filesystem.

So it is just a matter of composing into the HttpPut instance a StringEntity holding the absolute path to the GeoTIFF file.

```
String REST_API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest";
String workspacename = "myworkspace";
String coveragestorename = "mygeotiffname";
String coverageFormat  = "geotiff";

String url = REST_API_URL + "/workspaces/" + workspacename
    + "/coveragestores/" + coveragestorename
    + "/external."+ coverageFormat
    + "?configure=first&coverageName=" + coveragestorename ;
HttpPut request = // here create an org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut instance
                  // including Basic Auth
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
String data = // here provide ABSOLUTE path to GeoTIFF file;
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data, ContentType.create("text/plain", Consts.UTF_8));
request.setEntity(entity);
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

The returned responseCode should be 201 (HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)